# Backbone Marionette controller method not called from appRouter

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I am trying to trigger Marionette controller methods from a Marionette appRouter but the methods are not fired when they should.

You can take a look at my code at http://jsfiddle.net/gabceb/bW69k/

In summary the code initializes a controller, an appRouter and a Marionette application. I want the code to trigger the initialize on the controller (which it does) and the index method when the appropriate route is called. The code was ported and simplified from a real app to Fiddler so this is not Fiddler's fault.

*I also validated that the appRouter is using the correct controller by changing the appRouter's method to index1 and having the appRouter complain that the method does not exist (Note that this is only a test I made and is not actually implemented in the code that I posted on Fiddler)*

```
# app.coffee.js

class PagesController extends Marionette.Controller
    initialize: (options) =>
        alert "Controller initialized"

        return

    index: () =>
        alert "Index method called"

        return

class AppRouter extends Marionette.AppRouter
    appRoutes: {
       "" : "index"
    }

window.app = new Backbone.Marionette.Application()

window.app.addInitializer( (options) =>
    Backbone.history.start(pushState: true)
)

window.app.addInitializer( (options) =>
    window.app.appRouter = new AppRouter(controller : new PagesController())
)

window.app.start()
```

I've done some debugging regarding this and it looks like the Backbone.History handlers array is empty whenever the page is loaded. This is how the code looks like on the Backbone code.

```
// Attempt to load the current URL fragment. If a route succeeds with a
// match, returns `true`. If no defined routes matches the fragment,
// returns `false`.
loadUrl: function(fragment) {
  fragment = this.fragment = this.getFragment(fragment);
  return _.any(this.handlers, function(handler) {
    if (handler.route.test(fragment)) {
      handler.callback(fragment);
      return true;
    }
  });
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you create `AppRouter` after starting `Backbone.history`.

You can reed more about it here: [Right place to start Backbone.history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243334/right-place-to-start-backbone-history/22244057#22244057)

Comment: Thanks @Dmytro. That change did it. I've now changed my code to use initialize:after rather than having to worry about order of initializers. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

My CoffeeScript is hazy, but it look like you're initializing the appRouter wrong: you need to pass an object:

```
window.app.appRouter = new AppRouter({ controller : new PagesController() })
```

Comment: Brackets are not necessary on Coffeescript to pass  an object to a method. Try that line at http://js2coffee.org/ to see the JS code.